# Same roots, same polynomial? How to prove characteristic polynomial of $AB = BA$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

I'm giving a (simple) proof that the characteristic polynomial of $AB$ = characteristic polynomial of $BA$ (without using the fact that $AB$ and $BA$ are similar).

$det(AB) = det(A)det(B) = det(B)det(A) = det(BA)$. The determinants of $AB$ and $BA$ are equal. This entails that the roots of the characteristic polynomial of $AB = BA$. Can you infer from this that if the roots of a polynomials $p$a are $q$ are the same, then $p=q$?

If not, then I'm stuck on this proof, and some help would be appreciated.

Edit: It's official. I'm stuck on this proof. How do you prove this?

Comment: Are you asking about any two polynomials in general?

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but how does the equality of the roots of the characteristic polynomial follow from the equality of the determinants?

Comment: The product of the roots of the characteristic polynomial of a Matrix $M$ = det(M). That is $\prod \lambda_i$ = $det(M)$.

Comment: So the *product* of the respective roots is equal. That does not mean that the set of all roots is equal.

Answer (score 2):

This is not true in general. Knowing the roots of two polynomials are the same is not enough to conclude they are identical. Indeed, consider

$$p(X) = (1+X)(1-X)$$

and

$$q(X) = \frac{1}{2}(1+X)(1-X)$$

over $\mathbb{Q}$, say. These polynomials have the same roots, but $p \neq q$.

**update:** (thank you @quid for pointing this out)

Since you are working with characteristic polynomials we do have additional information, namely concerning the leading coefficient of each polynomial and that they factor completely as products of linear terms by definition. With this in mind, knowing the leading coefficients and roots of two characteristic polynomials (*and the multiplicity of each root*, which is absolutely necessary!) one can conclude that they polynomials are in fact equal.

Comment: That's true. But it might be worth adding that since in OP's situation the polynomials are normed (or at least one knows what the leading coefficient must be) it would in fact be sufficient to know that the roots (with multiplicty) are equal.

Comment: Yes, that is a good point. I wasn't sure what OP's questions was asking, so I made a general answer. I'll update my post to include that information.

Answer (score 1):

If $\det M=\det N$, all you can say is that the product of the eigenvalues of $M$ is the same as the product of the eigenvalues of $N$. For example, you could have the eigenvalues $2,1/2$ for $M$ and the eigenvalues $3,1/3$ for $N$.

Comment: Thank you. This has been pointed out by others. I'm looking to prove the cp of $BA = $ cp of $AB$.

Comment: @larry Have you tried proving it when $A$ is invertible?